# Using Poisson Distribution Method

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution, means

Q) The question is as follows:
suppose that a book of 200 pages contains 20 printing mistakes.Assume that are errors are randomly distributed throughout the book and *x* , the number of errors per page has a poisson distribution.Find the probability that 30 pages selected at random will be free of errors.

I could only come with the equation

$$\frac{e^{-20}20^{30}}{30!}.$$

But it is giving wrong answer.What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: The number of errors in $30$ pages has, under our (not precisely true)  assumptions Poisson distribution with parameter $(20/200)(30)=3$. The probability that a Poisson with parameter $3$ is equal to $0$ is $e^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rate is $1/10$ per page, so $\lambda=30/10=3$ for $30$ pages.  So you want a Poisson with $\lambda=3$. And then $Pr(x=0)=\frac{e^{-3}}{0!}10^{0}=e^{-3}$

Comment: Thank You.That's correct.The value of $$e^{-3}$$ is 0.049 which is approximately 0.05,which is the answer according to my textbook.

Answer (score 0):

The rate $\lambda$ can be seen as equal to 1 for 10 pages. We have 20 such 'stacks' of pages. The probability of success, is $e^{-1}$. Now use Binomial distribution for $k=3, n=k, p = e^{-1}$, so the probability of 3 successes in 3 trials is $\binom{3}{3} e^{-3}(1-e^{-1})^0 = e^{-3}$.

Comment: thanks.But can you please solve it with poisson distribution.
The answer according to text book is 0.05.And i am getting nowhere near to it.

Comment: Apologies. Please see the edit.